# Vue Google Maps - JavaScript API error: NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hi im trying to add my api key to my google map. when i used the string version of the key everything was fine, but i don't want to do that i would like to keep the key in my .env file. However when i make that change i can't get the Google Maps JavaScript API error: NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapsError. any help would be greatly appreciated!
thanks

*edit i just noticed that this issue is happening when i try to load the api key from my .env file. when i swap out the line with process.env.VUE_APP_GOOOGLEMAPS_KEY; and paste in the actual api key the map loads just fine.

MapPage.vue

```
    <template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Map</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
      <GoogleMap :api-key="API_KEY" style="width: 100%; height: 500px" :center="center" :zoom="15">
        <Marker :options="{ position: center }" />
      </GoogleMap>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue';
import { GoogleMap, Marker } from "vue3-google-map";

export default {
  name: 'MapPage',
  components: { IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonPage, GoogleMap, Marker },
  setup() {
    const center = { lat: 40.689247, lng: -74.044502 };
    const API_KEY = process.env.VUE_APP_GOOOGLEMAPS_KEY;

    return { center,API_KEY };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

NotLoadingAPIFromGoogleMapError

The Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from Google's servers.
The script element that loads the Maps JavaScript API is not being included correctly on your page. In order for the API to work correctly, it must be loaded directly from

https://maps.googleapis.com.

See Loading the Maps JavaScript API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript

It also occurs when using the original location for the google maps API (which worked for years):

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js

Changing that to (per the documentation link above):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js